# How to access Angular2 components methods while testing?

Tags: angular, testing, typescript, jasmine

So, I have Angular2 component that looks like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    user = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };

    constructor() {
    }

    login() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

And I have test suite set up (only relevant part showed):

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      imports: [FormsModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
it('should define method login()', () => {
    console.log(component);  //access data from component
    console.log(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement);  //access dom of component
  });

});
```

And I'm trying to write test for that login() function using Karma and Jasmine. But I simply can't access the login method. I've looked at a lot of sites, and most of them show examples with how to access properties, but never methods. Am I doing something wrong conceptually by trying to access class methods in test suite or something? (I'm not that good at testing)

Comment: You want to mock the methods. I asked a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915547/angular-2-jasmine-how-to-test-a-function-of-a-component

Comment: @Bhetzie Yeah, I saw that thread while I was searching, but that's part that I don't understand, why do I have to do it that way? I mean, why can't I directly call that method from class?

Something like: 

1. set the input //if needed

2. call the function directly

3. check if results are what I am expecting


 Am I missing something obvious about testing in general?

Answer (score 0):

The component that you assigned in the first before each is the instance of the LoginComponent that angular is using [see here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-a-component). Since login is public you should be able to call the method directly i.e. `component.login`.