# Test cases in angular

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to angular, I want to do the test cases to the below example . please explain me how to write a test cases for this login function by using karma or jasmine in angular?

```
            ngOnInit() {
            // reset login status
            this.authenticationService.logout();        
            // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
            this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
        }
        login() {
                this.loading = true;
                this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, 
                this.model.password)
                    .subscribe(
                        data => {this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                        },
                        error => {
                            this.alertService.error(error);
                            this.loading = false;
                        });
            }
```

Comment: Take a look at this discussion: [Angular 2 Jasmine How to test a function of a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915547/angular-2-jasmine-how-to-test-a-function-of-a-component)

Answer (score 0):

To write test case in angular you need to do followings:

> install karma and jasmine
>   do karma init 
>   create .spec file
>   write expectation using assertion library
>   for more help visit : https://jasmine.github.io/2.8/introduction

2.8 is the latest jasmine version

Comment: already i finished the installation process.now i have to write the testcase for that login function..suggest me few examples...for that.